# React Router 5+ HashRouter Handle Browser Back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am unable to handle the browser back button. What I want to do is alert the user that if they go back they will be taken to the home screen and must restart the flow they were in. I am using HashRouter, React Router v5.2.0. I tried the following but does not work

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'


const [ locationKeys, setLocationKeys ] = useState([])
const history = useHistory()

useEffect(() => {
  return history.listen(location => {
    if (history.action === 'PUSH') {
      setLocationKeys([ location.key ])
    }

    if (history.action === 'POP') {
      if (locationKeys[1] === location.key) {
        setLocationKeys(([ _, ...keys ]) => keys)

        // Handle forward event

      } else {
        setLocationKeys((keys) => [ location.key, ...keys ])

        // Handle back event

      }
    }
  })
}, [ locationKeys, ])
```

EDIT from the docs, HashRouter does not support location.key so the code snippet above should not work. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter

I also tried the following which gives undesired behavior. The confirmation is called twice depending on what is on the history stack. I also notice the browser url changes to the previous screen url before a user can confirm or cancel which seems to be causing this strange behavior.

```
  const listener = function (event) {
    console.log('back');
    if (confirm('are you sure?')) {
      console.log("go back to home";
    } else {
      console.log("stay")
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('popstate', listener, false);
    return () => {
      console.log('removing listener');
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', listener, false);
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the block method of history object

```
history.block(() => {
    /// your code           
});
```

Comment: I tried this but does not function correctly. If I confirm I get the confirmation dialog again (infinite loop). Also not sure how to cancel, I also see the url changing before confirmation of dialog box, similar to the previous behavior using event listener above.
```   useEffect(() => {
    const listener = history.block(() => {
      if (confirm('are you sure?')) {
        history.push('/');
      } else {
        // how to cancel?
      }
    });
    return () => {
      listener();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: you should return false to stop the url redirection.

Comment: nice that works. Still getting infinite confirmation loop though if I confirm yes.